# Rails respond_with works on Heroku but not on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a Rails 4 application that uses respond_with after creating or editing objects.

```
respond_with @account
```

In my staging environment on Heroku this works just fine, but on my AWS server it redirects to my root URL always. Since it works on Heroku this might have to do with the server?

Comment: Which RAILS_ENV are you running with on the two, respectively?

Comment: Can you paste you log here because it's hard to guess ?